# iron-ajax request results in cors issue with spring boot

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, polymer-2.x

Currently I face a CORS issue when doing an ajax call (with the iron-ajax element of Polymer 2) to my server, developed using Spring Boot 2.

Performing a post request to /login via Postman returns in the expected results, however, using a browser like Safari or Chrome results in the following error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

My configuration in the back-end looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // We filter the api/login requests
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Create a default account
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
     }
}
```

The ajax call is set up as follows:

```
<iron-ajax
  id="postLoginAjax"
  method="post"
  headers='{"access-control-allow-origin": "*"}' // Tried with and without
  content-type="application/json"
  handle-as"json"
  on-touch="touch"
  on-response="handleUserResponse"
  on-error"handleUserError">
</iron-ajax>
```

Based on other SO posts I have implemented the Bean, however still not successful.

**EDIT:**
Also following the global cors settings suggested at https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework does not result in what I want. I assume because it is relying on mvc dependency, which I am not using.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Chris

Comment: You should try adding the `with-credentials` attribute to your `iron-ajax` element.

Comment: Hi @codeMonkey I'll give that one a try too soon. In the meanwhile I have fixed it on the server side. Will update this SO this weekend. Will confirm your suggestion as well.

Comment: I'm facing  same issue in polymer 2.0 with spring boot.